# Distinguishing between an http call from a bot and a browser or app

Tags: http, bots, user-agent

As the User-Agent header can be manipulated by a bot, checking the User-Agent is not the right choice to distinguish between a bot and a real device i.e. browser or app.

Is there a solid way to distinguish between bots and devices or we have to live with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think basically you can't, not with a high confidence anyway.

An obvious way is to use a captcha to verify your operator is probably human.  These are annoying to actual people though.

Or set some cookies in javascript, although this is pretty simple to circumvent too.

Failing this, maybe look at the time differences between successive requests.  If they're coming milliseconds apart, then it's sure to be a bot.

Make an invisible link on the page (by manipulating the colours), and if something spiders that link, you can be sure you have a bot, or at least a curious human.